# Run jUnit tests using @category spring and gradle

Tags: java, spring, gradle, junit, mockito

I need to run some integration tests and some unit tests and I am using spring, gradle and jUnit 4.

I used jUnit categories @Category(UnitTestCategory.class) and @Category(IntegrationTestCategory.class) and i added

```
test {
    useJUnit {
    includeCategories 'org.gradle.junit.CategoryA'
    excludeCategories 'org.gradle.junit.CategoryB'
    }
}
```

for gradle in order to include/exclude a category. The idea is that i don't want to mix unit tests and integration test and i have a category for each of them.

The problem is that I must use both spring and categories and `@RunWith(...)` can receive only one `class param. - RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` or `@RunWith(Categories.class)` .

I couldn't use `@RunWith({Categories.class, SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class})` and I must run with spring and categories. Plus that in the future i might need to add also other classes not only spring and category. So i need multiple parameters for @RunWith(...)

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html

Does anyone have a solution please?

Comment: You don't have to use `@RunWith(Categories.class)` if you run your tests with Gradle. The `Categories` runner is only needed if you want to use a special Suite that you can start in your IDE.

Comment: Yes but i i have two test categories integration tests and unit tests and i don't want to mix them. I want to run only one category using includeCategories / excludeCategory in gradle.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of spring runner you can use [spring junit rules](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-junit4-rules). Then as a runner you can use `Categories`